# Missing "emailAddress" in response for some users

Tags: linkedin-api

My app is using linkedin as oauthd login method. For some of users there is no valid response when I'm trying to fetch email address (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/fields/basic-profile#email-fields)

Request:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))
```

Response:

```
200 {"elements":[]}
```

^^^ missing email field

```
200 {"elements":[{"handle":"urn:li:emailAddress:472511033","handle!":{"message":"Downstream service returned an empty response for URN.","status":404}}]}
```

OK, but failed?

Normal response looks like this:

```
200 {"elements":[{"handle~":{"emailAddress":"XXX@XXX"},"handle":"urn:li:emailAddress:XXX"}]}
```

Is there any settings in linkedin profile that blocks requesting emailAddress?

Answer (score 0):

I found in documentation that this is related to new users that was registered using phone.

> The API call would return empty response body if the authenticated user was registered via phone number, and never added any primary email address into their LinkedIn account previously. The value of type is case sensitive, and can only be EMAIL in this case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/primary-contact-api#retrieve-email-address